# sql scope and 'if exists' behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am writing a query that updates schema from an old table structure to a new one. I do not understand why this query:

```
if exists (
    select * 
    from information_schema.columns 
    where table_name = 'old_table' and column_name = 'old_col')
    begin
    update [dbo].[new_table] 
        set [new_table].[new_col] = [old_table].[old_col] 
        from [dbo].[new_table] 
        inner join [dbo].[old_table] on [new_table].[old_id] = [old_table].[old_id];
    --yada yada yada...
    alter table [dbo].[old_table] drop column [old_col];
    print 'old_table successfully migrated to new_table';
    end
else
    print 'no need to migrate old_table to new_table';
```

throws this exception:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7, 
Invalid column name 'old_col'.
```

when the `old_col` column no longer exits on `old_table` and I know this because:

```
select * 
    from information_schema.columns 
    where table_name = 'old_table' and column_name = 'old_col'
```

doesn't return any rows and I do not see the 'old_col' column in the `Object Explorer`.

What am I missing here? Why would the query within the conditional statement ever even run?

Comment: it's a compilation error, SQL Server have to check schema despite if statements

Comment: so do I need to do something like `if exists (...) exec sp_executesql('update ... drop column [old_col];')`?

Comment: yes, you can use dynamic SQL and it'll work alright, it has it's own scope